# How to handle auto suggestion web element in selenium 3

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am new on automation testing and have difficulty when trying to pratice using selenium 3 on booking.com website

There is auto suggestion text box, when you type word, shown auto suggestion and you can click from the list i.e Downtown Singapore

[image]

Have try with xpath `id("basiclayout")/div[@class="leftwide rilt-left"]/div[@class="sb-searchbox__outer"]/form[@id="frm"]/div[@class="sb-searchbox__row u-clearfix"]/div[1]/div[@class="c-autocomplete
sb-destination"]/ul[@class="c-autocomplete__list sb-autocomplete__list -visible"]/li[@class="c-autocomplete__item sb-autocomplete__item sb-autocomplete__item--city sb-autocomplete__item__item--elipsis"]`

or css `c-autocomplete__item sb-autocomplete__item sb-autocomplete__item--city sb-autocomplete__item__item--elipsis`

all scenario failed when i run my testcases on selenium java

How to handle on such web element?

**Complete code:**

```
public class Selenium3Testing {
private WebDriver driver;

@Before
public void setUp() {
    String baseUrl = "https://www.booking.com/";
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "src/test/resources/drivers/chromedriver.exe");
    DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
    driver = new ChromeDriver(capabilities);
    driver.get(baseUrl);
}

@After
public void tearDown() {
    driver.quit();
}

@Test
public void openBookingDotCom() {
    driver.findElement(By.id("ss")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.id("ss")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.id("ss")).sendKeys("Singapore");
    //click on auto suggestion row number 2
    driver.findElement(By.css("c-autocomplete__item sb-autocomplete__item sb-autocomplete__item--city sb-autocomplete__item__item--elipsis")).click();
    } 
}
```

Comment: Please read [ask], especially the part about [mcve] (MCVE), and [How much research effort is expected?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) This will help you debug your own programs and solve problems for yourself. If you do this and are still stuck you can come back and post your MCVE, what you tried, and the execution result including any error messages so we can better help you. Also provide a link to the page and/or the relevant HTML.

Comment: Can you share the URL & the exact manual steps you are trying to Automate?

Comment: updated my question with complete code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just typing from mobile, so no code, here the way we can do it.

For giving input to input box, I hope if we pass total word in sendkeys, suggestion's may not load or delayed. So best way I follow is pass each character..may be sleep say 300 milli sec for each char. Write as small method which will loop for all chars in word.

To click on suggestion list, try for xpath contains text..or any one works well.

Comment: Thanks it works when adding Thread.sleep after sendkeys command